# TeamCity - Setting up additional agent on same Win VM

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

How do I install another agent on the same Windows VM? I ran the MSI and installed it into another folder but it just unregistered the old one and the latest one took over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done so far is good, but its not the full story. For some God-forsaken reason, JetBrains made this super common thing, hard.

So you've one agent in `D:\Agent-A` and another in `D:\Agent-B` and during install you ensured they don't share any folders or ports etc.

Okay, now you have to open Notepad.exe as Administrator (to bypass the world's most annoying software 'feature', UAC) and edit:

`D:\Agent-B\launcher\conf\wrapper.conf` and near the bottom, append " B" to all the `wrapper.console.title` and `wrapper.ntservice.*` property values.

Now, open a Command Prompt as Administrator (to bypass the world's most annoying software 'feature', UAC) and CD into the following folder:

`D:\Agent-B\bin`

Now run:

`service.install.bat`

Check the outcome. Check that the new service appears in Windows. Start it. Wait for it to come online and authorize it in TC web UI if needed.

Done.